when I try await window.ai.canCreateTextSession() it replies 'there was no model available'
When Using canary on google chrome, I am trying out this api on windows:
await window.ai.canCreateTextSession()

unfortunately the app replies 'no' and "There was no model available."
How can I make the window.ai.canCreateTextSession model work?
Thanks in advance

Interestingly, I was given access by google to the feature and I still haven't been able to figure it out, but apparently one needs to have 22gb free disk as of this writing, I hope they make the model smaller

it turns out, when I used to run ai.canCreateTextSession() the model wasn't downloaded, so after I deleted some free disk space, many GBs, and then ran the function again, it replied "after-download" and,now, a few days later, it replies: "readily" and it finally works, so basically one has to use ai.canCreateTextSession() and one has to tell the user they need free disk in order to use the feature, I suspect people will need to have fallbacks in order to make a good user experience.
